# one to one field update serialization issue

Tags: django-rest-framework

###################### Requirement #############################

**/add_value/**

payload:
{
"profile_id": "34AB",
"amt": 100.00
}

######################      Viewset     ####################################

class cash_viewset(ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = Cashbalance.objects.all()
serializer_class = SampleSerializer
```

#######################  Models  ####################################

MOdel -1 ---

class Profile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
```

MOdel -2 ---

class Cashbalance(models.Model):

```
profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column="profile_id")
remianingAmount = models.FloatField()
amt = models.FloatField()
```

############################### Serializer ##############################

class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
profile_id = serializers.CharField(source="profile.profile_id")
remianingAmount = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = CashBalance
    fields = ["profile_id", "amt", "remianingAmount"]

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_dict = validated_data['profile']
    userprofile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id=profile_dict['profile_id'])
    bank_obj = CashBalance.objects.filter(profile_id=userprofile)
    bank_obj.update(amt=validated_data['amt'], remianingAmount=validated_data['amt'])
    return bank_obj[0]

def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(serializers.ModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    print(instance.profile.user.username)
    result = {"profile_id": data['profile_id'], "name": instance.profile.user.username,
              "remianingAmount": data['remianingAmount']}
    return result
```

################################# Question is ######################

Assume that, there is already some data in user,profile and Cashbalance tables

As per the payload given above,Based on the profile_id ,I have to update amt value to 100, for this I have implemented the solution in create method(create method given above),  please share your inputs ,I am hoping that update cannot be done in create method, how can i improve this in more good way according to my model designs by using modelviewset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the update, you have to override the update method in the serializer.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
  instance.profile.profile_id 
 = validated_data["profile"].get('profile_id',instance.profile.profile_id)
  instance.amt = validated_data.get('amt', instance.amt) 
  return instance
```

in your viewset

```
def update(self,request,pk=None):
   profile_id = request.data.get("profile_id")
   profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id = profile_id)
   ser = self.get_serializer_class()(instance=profile.cash_balance , data = request.data)
   ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
   ser.save()
```

in your CashBalanceModel, pass a related_name

```
profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column="profile_id" , related_name="cash_balance")
```

check docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Thank you for reply, Error is giving at first line as - AttributeError: 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'profile_id'

when i check the type of instance it is showing as modelbase and 

if i print "instance" it is giving as <class 'my_models.Cashbalance'>

if i do print(instance.profile.profile_id) - the same error as first line

Comment: this approach is fine when i am using endpoint url as "/add_value/{pk}" Just want to understand, my requirement to use endpoint as "/add_value/" and payload also given above, So i belive this approach wont suits the requirment , kindly suggest, how to update the table in other way by taking payload

Comment: if want to do so, you need to override the update method in your viewset aswell. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes its working fine, Thanks a lot for helping on this., as executed in local machine,  in viewset, create method should be present instead of update and Response object to be returned, then its working perfect and also instance.save() in serializer, then its updating perfectly, Thank you